# $f^2(x)-g^2(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the following task. Let $f$ and $g$ be two differentiable functions with $f'=g$ and $g'=f$, $f(0)=1$, $g(0)=0$. Show that:
$f^2(x)-g^2(x)=1$

I have two ideas on how to approach a solution but stuck at a certain point.

When I define $\lambda(x)=f^2(x)-g^2(x)$ and calculate $\lambda'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)-2g(x)g'(x)= C = 0$

(by using $f'=g$ and $g'=f$). Hence $\lambda(x)$ is constant.

I now have to show that $C = 1$ but have no Idea how to do that.

Comment: What is $\lambda(0)$?

Comment: Okay that is embarassing. Thank you! Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: You can post your own answer.  You did $99.99\%$ of the work, just missed the last observation.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719738/42969

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is just calculating $\lambda(0)$ which is $\lambda(0) = 1 - 0 = 1$.

Since $\lambda$ is constant $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ it is $1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You meant $\lambda(0) = 1$ and not $0$?

Answer (score 1):

$f'=g, g'=f$ multiplying $ff'=gg'$;
Integrating
$$\frac{f^2}{2}- \frac{g^2}{2}=\frac{C}{2}$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.
From BC at $x=0$
$$ C=1^2-0^2 =1$$
$$f^2- g^2=1.$$

Known elementary functions of $x$ are respectively
$$ f,g= \cosh,\sinh ;$$

$\lambda(x)$ should be constant, else it would not disappear on differentiating.