# Show that $f(x)+g(x)=e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665401/f2x-g2x-1) question:

Let $f$ and $g$ be two differentiable functions with $f'=g$ and $g'=f$, $f(0)=1$, $g(0)=0$ and $f^2(x)-g^2(x)=1$

can anybody explain me how we get to the proof that: $f(x)+g(x)=e^x$?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't encourage low-quality questions by answering in the comments please!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calculate the derivative of $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ gives $h'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x)$ which is $h'(x) = g(x)+f(x)=h(x)$.

If we define $c=1$ then $h'(x)=c*h(x)$ *and* *we know that when the derivative of a function $f$ can be formulated as $f'(x) = c*f(x)$ we can write $f(x)=f(0)*e^{cx}=1*e^x=e^x$.* Hence $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)=e^x$.

The italic part is a prove by itself, which I used from a maths book.